# Split a String and get each segment's start index

Tags: scala, indexing, split

I'm trying to split a String and get all the start indexes of each "word" that I get.

For example for such a String:

```
"Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots"
```

How can I split it to get each word's index?:

```
0,7,14,19,21,27,31,36,43,49
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this

```
val str="Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots"
val indexArr=str.split(" ").scanLeft(0)((prev,next)=>prev+next.length+1).dropRight(1)
```

Sample Output:

```
ndexArr: Array[Int] = Array(0, 7, 14, 19, 21, 27, 31, 36, 43, 49)
```

Comment: `str(57)` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. It removed

Comment: yes, but given string has single space as delimiter so its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that works even if delimiters are not constant in width (not only for delimiters with length `1`).

1. Instead of a single delimiter `FOO`, use combination of look-ahead and look-behind `(?<=FOO)|(?=FOO)`.
2. Scan over the lengths of tokens and delimiters, accumulate their lengths to obtain start indices
3. Throw away every second entry (the delimiters)

In code:

```
val txt = "Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots"
val pieces = txt.split("(?= )|(?<= )")
val startIndices = pieces.scanLeft(0){ (acc, w) => acc + w.size }
val tokensWithStartIndices = (pieces zip startIndices).grouped(2).map(_.head)

tokensWithStartIndices foreach println
```

Result:

```
(Rabbit,0)
(jumped,7)
(over,14)
(a,19)
(fence,21)
(and,27)
(this,31)
(Rabbit,36)
(loves,43)
(carrots,49)
```

Here are some intermediate outputs, so you can better understand what's going on in each step:

```
scala> val txt = "Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots"
txt: String = Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots

scala> val pieces = txt.split("(?= )|(?<= )")
pieces: Array[String] = Array(Rabbit, " ", jumped, " ", over, " ", a, " ", fence, " ", and, " ", this, " ", Rabbit, " ", loves, " ", carrots)

scala> val startIndices = pieces.scanLeft(0){ (acc, w) => acc + w.size }
startIndices: Array[Int] = Array(0, 6, 7, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 26, 27, 30, 31, 35, 36, 42, 43, 48, 49, 56)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be accurate even if the line starts with a space, or you have multiple spaces or tabs separating some words.  It traverses the `String` noting the transition from any white-space character (space, tab, newline, etc.) to a non-space character.

```
val txt = "Rabbit jumped over a fence and this Rabbit loves carrots"

txt.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((Seq.empty[Int],true)){case ((s,b),(c,i)) =>
    if (c.isWhitespace) (s,true)
    else if (b) (s :+ i, false)
    else (s,false)
}._1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative mixing `zipWithIndex` and [`collect`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):List[B]):

```
0 :: str.zipWithIndex.collect { case (' ', i) => i + 1 }.toList
```

Prepending the index of the first word isn't very elegant and it only allows using delimiters of length 1; but it's decently minimal and readable.